# Where can I find the Google email address used for integrating Thunderbird Lightning with Google calendar?

Tags: thunderbird, google-calendar

Several instances of Thunderbird Lightning have been setup to use Google Calendar however no seems to know which Gmail email account it is tied to. Is there a way I can find out so that the users can assign the appropriate permissions to who can read and edit the calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties of the calendar you can see the email address of the associated account, but I guess you mean the login credentials?

This is in  Tools/Options/Security/Passwords/Saved Passwords

Look for the https://calendar.google.com entry and the username should be alongside it.

Comment: I did attempt that however no email address is displayed. Are you able to upload screenshots of what you mean? The login credentials are do not appeared under 'Saved Passwords'

Comment: Are you saying you have no credentials stored there at all, or nothing for google?   Is it possible the calendar is a public view and so doesn't require credentials?

Comment: None are stored in there. It is possible that it is for public viewing but we need to change the settings however cannot find the UserID or email address it is using?

Comment: If you go to the calender properties and get the url of the calendar, then paste it into the address bar of a browser session that is not logged into any google services, can you see the calendar?  If so, it is a public calendar and so no credentials are needed.

Comment: This answer has been accepted - what was the outcome?